# Performance of my permalink structure?

Tags: permalinks, database, performance

I have read the discussion on the performance of different permalinks on the wp hackers mailinglist, THIS forum and around Google.

I could however not really deduce if the permalink structure I have been using for the past years is good or not:

```
/%postname%-%year%%monthnum%%day%.html
```

This combination put the postname directly after the / and the year,month,day combination makes it more unique since many postnames carry the same name. The html addition is something I have been using for the past 10 years on my blog (even pre wordpress) so that is legacy.

I dont know if this is good for permance or bad for performance, how can i check this?

(I have been running the blog for +10 years and there are about 10.000 posts with many links in)

links:

1. http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks
2. http://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+category+permalink+performance
3. http://ottopress.com/2010/category-in-permalinks-considered-harmful/
4. http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2010-October/035458.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check by looking at the size of the rewrite_rules option in the database. If it's small (which I believe it should with this structure), you're not using verbose rules. By contrast, if you see several lines per static page, you're using verbose rules and it's not good.

Comment: unfortunately... there are several lines per static page GRIN. So this is probably not a good permalink structure...hmmmm... this does explain an error message I got a while ago "WordPress database error Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet", I had to increase this setting in MySql.

Comment: then again... if you keep adding pages during years you will automatically get max_allowed_packet no matter what... unless you revert to non pretty permalinks... (i think) so... to be scalable for the next 30 years :) I will probably have to revert to non pretty permalinks. I think.

Comment: As long as you're using non verbose rules your page, attachment and custom post type rules are generic. So pretty links are quite safe in practice, so long as they're using a non verbose structure.

Answer (score 1):

I veto the accepted answer. The complexity of the rewrite rules is in no way a measure for the performance of article lookup.

In particular, it seems that starting your permalinks with post names is bad; see http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Structure_Tags

Without having looked into Wordpress code, I can imagine that they somehow index posts hierarchically. Therefore, the variables used in permalinks should be ordered from left to right from the most general to the most post specific variable used. This heuristic strongly favors the standards year/month/name or category/name.

Comment: `category/name` is actually known and confirmed as causing performance issues if large amount of pages is present. It is not as much related to speed of lookup as to deducing correct object to serve and complexity of rewrite rules **is** completely relevant.

Comment: Can you give a doc/code reference please? I just skimmed the code `(wp-include/rewrite.php` and `wp-include/query.php`); while is looks really awful and unnecessarily complicated, it appears that basically the parts are collected and identified and then directly inserted into SQL queries. I still cannot see why this should take longer for different orders. But when the db-query is executed, several joins have to be performed and _here_ order really matters. I seem to remember that MySQL is particularly bad at optimising join order.

Comment: I am not too deep into DB theory, but you have to keep products small. In any case, this might be a bug in the sense that it is programmed not as efficiently as it could be.

Comment: Well... i read that starting with post names was bad AND the other answer shows indeed multiple lines per entry (but for my 10.000 posts blog which i run on wordpress for years there is probably not much I change without losing a lot of references). I did not completely understand your answer here and the "veto" though, what do i need to do when you veto an answer????

Comment: I only wrote "veto", there is no such function here. My point is that higher runtime is caused by more code being executed or the DBMS. Since I could not find any reason that would suggest that different order of URL components should increase the amount of code run, I claim the reason lies with the database queries. But with that many posts, maybe any order is slow _because you have so many posts_. Do you use caching?

Comment: Err, no offense, but vetoing an answer without having thoroughly studied the WP code doesn't make much sense. FWIW, I authored, fixed and optimized enough WP code in general, and WP permalinks code in particular, to know what scales and what doesn't. ;-) Verbose rules can lead to a huge setting in the options table, that then needs to be pulled from the database (or memcached) and unserialized on every page load. I've seen the latter use-case bring a moderately loaded bi-xeon server to a crawl in 2006.

Comment: Well, then you should be able to give more specifics than "don't be verbose". What is verbosity here? Does the order of variables matter? (since Codex says it does and what you say does not explain this at all!) Furthermore, if this setting has to be pulled once per page load, why does the effect increase the more posts there are? Should deserializing not be _fast_? But, yes, certainly, I am thinking on the level of what makes sense, not what is in the code. Not all code makes sense.

Comment: the Codex give "A few HINTS" (see Codex) and does not specificy the complete algorithm. It does however point to http://ottopress.com/2010/category-in-permalinks-considered-harmful/ and http://comox.textdrive.com/pipermail/wp-testers/2009-January/011097.html all in all there is a sort of friction between best practices of url hacking in the field of human computer interaction and performance from the field of performance improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer ottopress. It appaers that changing conventions such that every page url would start with `/page/` and every post url with `/post/`, removing the unambiguity. You should be able to do this yourself, adding the fixed text to your permalink structure. This would probably be a good decision, anyways; what happens if I have a post BAR in category FOO and a page BAR that is subpage of FOO? Both would be addressed by `/foo/bar/` assuming the %category%/%postname% scheme. Or are slugs globally unique?

Comment: Oh, and as I understand it not having many posts breaks this system but having many pages, right? Since Wordpress started out as blogging system, this made sense. Then.

Comment: Yeah, having many pages and attachment is bad with verbose rules, but not having many posts. The reason is, wp assumes it's a post unless a rule specifies otherwise. Verbose rules were introduced when wp introduced pages, way back in 2005, in order to avoid permalink collisions with posts. There are still several tickets (some with patches, some without) that try to improve things on this front.

Comment: Oh, and, in case it's unclear what verbose rules are, the gist of it is, each page, attachment, and custom post type, instead of using a generic regex to identify all data of that type, ends up with several rules and thus regex -- again, per page, attachment, or custom post type. This alone is enough to slow things down significantly, but the real bottle neck is actually related to pulling and unserializing the rules in the first place.

Comment: So what could be solved by simple regexp matching is bloated to a horrible mess just because some assumptions from the beginning do no longer apply. Is there a particular reason why the behaviour has not been changed? Fear because old links would break? In particular, the distinction between pages and posts seems artificial nowadays, but that is another topic.

Comment: "reason why not changed" --> http://core.trac.wordpress.org/search?q=permalinks

Comment: 618 bugs are a reason to do it whole new, not to keep it.

Comment: @Raphael: I suspect everyone here will agree on that. But as each of us who actually contribute patches to WP core know, and as quite a few of those 618 search results will reveal (they're not all bugs, btw: notice the patches and changesets too), the WP core devs do not readily commit contributed bug fixes and enhancements. In particular when they're non-trivial enhancements.

Comment: Of course. You do not want to be responsible for a break you did not even code yourself. But we get new features all the time; maybe a feature freeze until some issues (I suspect there are more rough edges in WP) are handled is in order?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the workflow QA:

The answer is: NO this is not a good permalink structure concerning performance.